# Convert Date format from dd-mmm-yyyy (16-May-2013) to mm/dd/yyyy (09/12/2013)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to convert date format from dd-mmm-yyyy (16-May-2013) 
to date format mm/dd/yyyy (09/12/2013).

I am using this code. But still not able to get the correct value. the month value is becoming zero.

```
string dt = DateTime.Parse(txtVADate.Text.Trim()).ToString("mm/dd/yyyy");
```

In the above code txtVADate is the TextBox Control Which is giving date format 
like
 dd-mmm-yyyy example    (16-May-2013).

Any Answers are appreciable.

Comment: You can look this up in the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The format specifier for month is `MM` not `mm`, try using `MM/dd/yyyy`. Also when using a custom format it's best to pass `InvariantCulture` to avoid any clashes with the current culture your app is running under i.e.

```
DateTime.Parse(txtVADate.Text.Trim()).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

See [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

Use capital `M` letter.
m - minute
M - month

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware of that and wasted sometime

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `MM` instead of `mm` and `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as second parameter

```
string dt = DateTime.Parse(txtVADate.Text.Trim()).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

The slashes `/` mean: "replace me with the actual current date-separator of your culture-info".

To enforce `/` as separator you can use [`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx):

```
string dt = DateTime.Parse(txtVADate.Text.Trim())
    .ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> /
>    The date separator defined in the **current**
>   System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.DateSeparator property that is
>   used to differentiate years, months, and days.

( you also have to use MM instead of mm since lower case is minute whereas uppercase is month )

Comment: I don't think this answer deserves the downvote, yes the format should be `MM` for month, but that is not the real issue OP is facing, the issue was date-separator.

Answer (score 0):

```
string dt = datatime.toshortdatestring`
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution.

```
using System.Globalization;

 string dt = DateTime.Parse(txtDate.Text.Trim()).ToString("mm/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

also can be done like this

```
 public string FormatPostingDate(string txtdate)
 {
     if (txtdate != null && txtdate != string.Empty)
     {
         DateTime postingDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtdate);
         return string.Format("{0:mm/dd/yyyy}", postingDate);
     }
     return string.Empty;
 }
```